# OpenSCAD: Using outline of 2D shape

Tags: 2d

```
module initial(letter, size) {
  linear_extrude(height=size*4, center=true) {
    text(letter, size=size, halign="center", valign="center", font=font);
  }
}
```

I'm using this module to generate very tall letters that I then cut out of other shapes using "difference".

This works well for some letters (like M), but leaves detached pieces floating in the middle for letters like "O" or "A".

I'd like to know how to get just the outline of the letter without changing the shape of that outline the way the "hull" function would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(5 years, 3 months later)

You might like https://github.com/openscad/openscad/pull/4348 which adds a `fill()` builtin to do just this ... it just got merged :-)

[image: OpenSCAD, filled]